# What is wrong with this code to retrieve bgr values of an image using the step method

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is the code I got from a reputable source but its not working:

```
    Mat img = imread("/home/w/d1",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img.data);

       int i,j,r,g,b;
        for(int i = 0;i < img.rows ;i++){
                for(int j = 0;j < img.cols ;j++){
                    b = input[img.step * j + i ] ;
                    g = input[img.step * j + i + 1];
                    r = input[img.step * j + i + 2];
            cout << b << g <<r;
                }
            }
```

When I run it the output isn't the same as when I do a cout << img;
I think it might be something to do with the new C++ interface. If that is so and I'm supposed to use the step1 method, can some one show me how to update my code to access BGR values with the step1 method. I couldn't find online doc. on how to use step1. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: is it just the console output, that *looks* wrong ? cout treats single uchars as 'letters'. try `cout << int(b) << int(g) << int(r);`

Comment: @berak `r`,`g` and `b` are `int` values!

Comment: your order is wrong: since `j` is cols and `i` is rows you must acces with `input[img.step * i + j + channel];`

Comment: ah, ofc. Micka's right.

Comment: and in addition: the COL has to be multiplied with the number of channels!! forgot that in my unedited answer

Comment: @berak Thanks to everybody for the help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks basically right, but as far as I see, your ordering is wrong.
You must access

`value = data[img.step*ROW + COL]` but you have row and col switched.

edit: in addition you need to multiply the COL with the number of channels:

`value = data[img.step*ROW + #channels*COL + currentChannel]`

try:

```
Mat img = imread("/home/w/d1",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img.data);

   int i,j,r,g,b;
    for(int i = 0;i < img.rows ;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < img.cols ;j++){
                b = input[img.step * i + 3*j ] ; // 3 == img.channels()
                g = input[img.step * i + 3*j + 1];
                r = input[img.step * i + 3*j + 2];
        cout << b << g <<r;
            }
        }
```

Comment: had to edit that serveral times and didn't test it, so feel free to find more bugs :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to avoid the 'raw data' approach:

```
for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++) {
        Vec3b pix = img.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
        cout << int(pix[0]) << int(pix[1]) << int(pix[2]) << endl;
    }
}
```